# Renaming Stored Procedure Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to rename stored procedure dynamically.

For Example:

if my procedure name is:'usp_sg_Cons_Data'

I want to do something like:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'usp_sg_Cons_Data','usp_sg_Cons_Data__' + Current datetimestamp
```

So if i Execute the above it should rename 'usp_sg_Cons_Data' to 
'usp_sg_Cons_Data__201111081402'

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: are you using renaming as a substitution for source control?

Comment: I'm quite curious about why you need this, it feels wrong in many ways

Comment: @BlackTigerX this is a small code of bigger code basically what it does is it will check whether the procedure exists or not if it exists it will rename the existing procedure with datetimestamp and if it doesn't exist it will just create procedure

Comment: I really don't understand why you need to rename the procedure, this looks like one of the craziest design issues I ever seen.  If you need to check\store some date in relation to the procedure being put into the database, just create a database ddl trigger and parse out the procedure name and store a date in a table for that procedure.  I would rather store the data within a comment inside the procedure and use sys.sql_modules to extract/query for it. hacking a date onto the procedure name is just crazy and presents a whole host of issue, as you are becoming aware.

Comment: why doesn't your code work? your dynamic sql looks like it produces valid sql.  your question is misleading, you ask why can't you do `EXEC sp_rename 'usp_sg_Cons_Data','usp_sg_Cons_Data__' + Current datetimestamp` when your code does not do that.  You can't have a stored proc param use string concatenation, bad= `exec YourProcedure 'para'+'meter'`.  you need to resolve the concatenation in another way, like in a variable before the EXEC and pass in the variable.  By building the dynamic sql, it is resolved, so your code will produce a valid rename EXEC command, so what is the problem/error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @oldname varchar(100), @newname varchar(100);
SET @oldname = 'usp_sg_Cons_Data'
SET @newname = @oldname + CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 120)
EXEC sp_rename @oldname,@newname
```

Pick your [chosen CONVERT style here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: i cannot use that my problem is I have a piece of code which outputs the exec rename statement as output so it gives me procname along with datetimestamp but if i run that exec statement twice it throws me an error that's why i want to do something that gives me timestamp dynamically

Comment: @peter: you can't without some dynamic SQL or local variable. And I don't understand your reasoning for not being able to do this.